# I'm trying to simplify and automate formatting from multiple Word sources

Tags: vba, ms-word, formatting

I'm a *very* novice programmer (think code-enthusiastic English major) trying to do something that I think should be very straightforward. For work I have to incorporate materials from multiple Word-using sources, all of whom have different settings for various styles. So Alan will have Heading 1 be, for example, 14 pt Arial, while Beth's Heading 1 will be 16 pt Courier New, and the standard for my org for Heading 1 is 18 pt Calibri. The different styles can quickly pile up, and even if you change the imported materials to fit what is correct, there's a bunch of material in there that can cause issues.

What I'd like is to build a VBA macro that runs through the document and essentially says, "this is Body? Cool, all Body text is set to these settings. This is Heading 1? All Headings 1 should be XYZ," and then goes through and does those conversions. I got an O'Reilly book on writing macros for Word, but I quickly got in over my head. Any suggestions on how to start, or where to look?

Thanks in advance.

ETA
My code is now at this point:

Sub test()

Set objDoc = ActiveDocument

' First, highlight the entire document in the default color (i.e. the color to use for styles that aren't defined in our guide)

objDoc.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdDarkYellow

' Need to figure out how to do color code (RGB) this works for now.

reformatStyle "Heading 1", False, "Calibri", wdBlack, 16

reformatStyle "Body"

' Call reformatStyle once for each style, setting the appropriate values for bold, fontName, color and size.

' valid colors are at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdcolorindex

End Sub

Sub reformatStyle(style, bold, fontName, color, fontSize)

```
With objDoc.Content.Find

    .ClearFormatting

    .style = style

    ' this first bit selects the blocks that have the specified style
    With .Replacement

        .Font.bold = bold

        .Font.Name = fontName

        .Font.ColorIndex = color

        .Font.Size = fontSize

        .Highlight = False

        ' this modifies the selected blocks. Note that we remove the highlighting at this point, otherwise it would remain at the default color

    End With

    .Execute Wrap:=wdFindContinue, Format:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End With
```

End Sub

What I'd like to do is be able to set the color to RGB values. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.copystylesfromtemplate

Comment: If you use the 'match destination Styles' option when copying & pasting content from other documents, that should be enough to take care of the issue. In any other case, selecting the entire document, then pressing Ctrl-Spacebar should be sufficient to re-apply the underlying Style formatting to the entire document.